# Basic SELECT query - results from multiple database

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need help with a basic MySQL / SQL related question.

I have 2 tables:

**Table1**

```
house_id | house address | house_type_id |
------------------------------------------
    1    |  John str.    |   33
    2    |  Peter str.   |   41
    3    |  Louis str.   |   33
    4    |  Harold str.  |   17
```

**Table2**

```
house_type_id | house_type_description
--------------------------------------
     33       |    Big
     41       |    Medium
     17       |    Small
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
house_id | house address | house_type_id |
------------------------------------------
    1    |  John str.    |   Big
    2    |  Peter str.   |   Medium
    3    |  Louis str.   |   Big
    4    |  Harold str.  |   Small
```

I tried to following statement, but it doesn't make the required output:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2 Where Table1.house_type_id = Table2.house_type_id
```

Could you help me what is the problem ?

Comment: Simple syntax error. Table should be Table2. But you should use JOIN for better syntax

Comment: When you use `*` you select all columns from all tables in the from and join clauses; it you want any specific columns you have to specify them explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Amit and jpw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
 SELECT house_id , house address, house_type_description 
 FROM Table1 inner join Table2
 on Table1.house_type_id = Table2.house_type_id
```

Comment: @TassMark your welcome, If the answer is ok, please do not forget to mark is as accepted. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```css
select a.house_id,a.house address,b.house_type_description from table1 a left join table2 b on a.house_type_id = b.house_type_id
```

Comment: Why use a `left join`? Nothing in the question suggests that the OP would want that and not an `inner join`.